# csrf_exempt Decorator does not work in Dajngo function based views

Tags: django, reactjs, csrf-token

I am using React with Django, most of the client server interaction is being done through the API using Django Rest Framework. I created a standard app called `mail`, it has a standard view which accepts a `POST` request with `csrf_exempt` and `login_required` decorators on it. However whenever making an `ajax` call through `Axios` it always gives me a `403 Invalid CSRF Token error - CSRF Cookie not specified.`

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def testmail(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        EmailQueue.objects.create(subject='TEST EMAIL BROTHER', body=render_to_string('nordalmail/testmail.html'), to_email=request.user.email, from_email=settings.FROM_EMAIL, send_now=True)
        return HttpResponse("CHECK ADMIN")
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "nordalmail/test-mail.html")
```

React Component

```
import axios from 'axios';                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
import {createMessage, returnErrors} from './messages.js';
import {tokenConfig} from './auth.js';

// Tokenconfig simply gets the Authorization Token and sends it as a Header value 

export const sendTestMail = () => (loggedUserEmail, getState) => {
    axios
        .post('http://alice:55403/nordalmail/', tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res => {
            createMessage("A test email has been sent to your registered email address!",
            "Email Sent");
        })  
        .catch(err => {
            returnErrors("Something went wrong while sending your email, website administrator has been notified of this incidence!", "Error");
        }); 
}
```

Here's the Request I send

```
Request URL: http://alice:55403/nordalmail/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:55403
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
headers: {"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Token 35a7aa30b26ebb1c269c6cca0cd323c07e028171aa268b61d0dfc41871f93de6"}}
```

I am using `brave browser` so I don't really know how to get the `raw headers`. I can vouch for the validity of this `Authorization Token` as it does work on other proper API endpionts.

Comment: try django-cors-headers instead.

Comment: I already am using them. That's how React is able to make calls to the Django server.

Comment: i get it +1 for that i am also stuck in csrf cookie problem, the easy workaround that i came to know is to comment the csrf_middleware, and i know thats not great solution :D (I am using angular->django, BTW how is react)

Comment: I suppose that's going to be my end solution as well. And react is pretty good. Setting up redux was a pain though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because of the fact that my `app_name` and the `url` that's used to access the `app` itself are the same. So my `app_name` is `nordalmail` and my `url` to access the app is also nordalmail.

Now here's the real problem, I have set the `root` of my website to be the actual admin panel provided by `Django` itself. So when I made a request to `/nordalmail` it actually rendered the model lists in the app. All I had to do was change the URL and it worked.

Comment: Have you get the workaround for not doing (comment the csrf_middleware)?

Comment: Acutally `@csrf_exempt` worked well for me, as I said the URL I was hitting through React was simply the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

I started a project that requires to accept POST from an external application to django, somehow I wrote the following line in the project urls `path('', admin.site.urls, name='admin')` I didn't realize right away but this path caused @csrf_exempt to be ignored in my function-based views.